# Central Directory corrupt error occurs when deploying Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions

I get the below Central Directory corrupt error when deploying an azure function using the following Azure Function Core Tools command line "func azure functionapp publish ".

Does anyone have any idea what causes this?

Azure Function Core Tools Version is 2.7.2254.

**Full Error Text**
Error uploading archive (InternalServerError).
Server Response: {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Central Directory corrupt.","ExceptionType":"System.IO.InvalidDataException","StackTrace":"   at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.ReadEndOfCentralDirectory()\r\n   at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.Init(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen)\r\n   at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive..ctor(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen, Encoding entryNameEncoding)\r\n   at System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.Open(String archiveFileName, ZipArchiveMode mode, Encoding entryNameEncoding)\r\n   at Kudu.Services.Deployment.PushDeploymentController.ExtractTriggers(IRepository repository, ZipDeploymentInfo zipDeploymentInfo) in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Services\Deployment\PushDeploymentController.cs:line 329\r\n   at Kudu.Services.Deployment.PushDeploymentController.d__14.MoveNext() in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Services\Deployment\PushDeploymentController.cs:line 315\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Kudu.Core.Deployment.FetchDeploymentManager.d__9.MoveNext() in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Deployment\FetchDeploymentManager.cs:line 235\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Kudu.Core.Deployment.FetchDeploymentManager.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Deployment\FetchDeploymentManager.cs:line 115\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Kudu.Contracts.Infrastructure.LockExtensions.d__5`1.MoveNext() in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Contracts\\Infrastructure\\LockExtensions.cs:line 100\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Kudu.Core.Deployment.FetchDeploymentManager.<FetchDeploy>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Core\\Deployment\\FetchDeploymentManager.cs:line 108\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)\r\n   at Kudu.Services.Deployment.PushDeploymentController.<PushDeployAsync>d__12.MoveNext() in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Services\\Deployment\\PushDeploymentController.cs:line 221\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Kudu.Services.Deployment.PushDeploymentController.<ZipPushDeploy>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Services\\Deployment\\PushDeploymentController.cs:line 95\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()","InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"An attempt was made to move the file pointer before the beginning of the file.\r\n","ExceptionType":"System.IO.IOException","StackTrace":"   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)\r\n   at System.IO.FileStream.SeekCore(Int64 offset, SeekOrigin origin)\r\n   at System.IO.FileStream.Seek(Int64 offset, SeekOrigin origin)\r\n   at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.ReadEndOfCentralDirectory()"}}

Comment: Is it firewall related? Can you try in a different network? And what the language you are using now?

Answer (score 0):

**First,**

please make sure there is no problem when you debug on local.

**Second,**

please out the possibility of firewall related. And try to publish to a new functionapp.

**Third,**

please make sure the structure of your function app in the folder you want to publish is correct.

[C# class library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#functions-class-library-project), [C# script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#folder-structure), [F#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-fsharp#folder-structure), [JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#folder-structure), [Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-java#folder-structure), [Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#folder-structure), [TypeScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#folder-structure).

**Then at last,**

you can use this command to publish your function app:

```
func azure functionapp publish yourfunctionappnameonazure --force
```

Comment: I can run the app fine locally in debug mode from Visual Studio and from azure after deploying it to the cloud with visual studio 2017.

Comment: @user3845056 So there is no problem now? In the end, you deployed it with VS 2017 and succeeded?

Comment: I want to deploy with the command line so there is still a problem.